# Vim - in HTML files, is auto indenting the closing tags possible?

Tags: html, vim, indentation

Is it possible to get Vim to auto indent closing tags in HTML? Here is an illustration of the issue I am having:

[image]

You can see that it indents the opening tags perfectly but when I have a closing tag, they don't indent in line with the opening one. To be clear here is how I would want that example to indent:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
        thing
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to fix this?

I know about running <kbd>gg=G</kbd> to indent the file at the end but I'm specifically looking to get the indenting happening as I type.

As an aside, in Sublime Text 3 I get around the issue using Emmet – each time you expand it places the cursor in the correct position. However, the Vim version behaves oddly, failing to auto indent so that's not a possible solution either.

In case relevant, here is a link to my current .vimrc: https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a

Comment: Just curious. What program did you use to create the animated gif?

Comment: merlin2011 - recorded with QuickTime then converted with GIFBrewery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you ask for has been the default behavior for quite a while. The default Vim on Mac OS X (7.3.000, released in 2010) does that and the latest MacVim (7.4.258) does that too.

Could you post your `~/.vimrc`, please?

***edit***

I tested your `vimrc`, with all the vundle stuff, all the mappings to non-existing commands, and generally stuff that couldn't work here (backupdir, colorscheme…) commented out and I get the normal and expected behavior.

I would suggest you bisect your vundle plugins.

FWIW, there are a few mistakes in your `vimrc` but they don't seem to have any impact on your current problem:

- ['smartindent'](https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a#file-vimrc-L248) is useless and should be avoided,
- [this](https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a#file-vimrc-L247) is redundant because of [that](https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a#file-vimrc-L40),
- you must not put comments after mappings, [here](https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a#file-vimrc-L292), [here](https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a#file-vimrc-L293), [here](https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a#file-vimrc-L296).

Comment: Hi romainl - my Vimrc is here: https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a

Comment: Thanks romainl. I appreciate that. On the comments after mappings — should that stop them working (as those mappings work fine for me)? I will amend either way but just curious. Thanks again.

Comment: See `:help map-comments`.

Comment: In case of future searchers. I had a plugin called 'AutoComplPop' that was causing this issue. Once commented out, indentation worked as expected.

Comment: @BenFrain, ACP is not the culprit, here, it's omni-completion. Even using the built-in `<C-x><C-o>` (used under the hood by ACP) will exhibit that unwanted behavior while typing `</div><CR>` won't.

Comment: Oh... Is there a way around this? I'm trying to get Plugins out of my vimrc at present but perhaps one of the ones Edmond mentions will fix this behaviour?

Comment: #2075 is the one shipped in Vim. #1830 seems too old. Try them if you want but I doubt they will fix omni-completion's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing one of the alternative HTML indentation plugins, which will also address other quirks in addition to closing tags:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1830